# libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file

Tags: python-3.x, shared-libraries

I catch this error when trying to run Django database migration:

```
File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/xxx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/drf_ujson/renderers.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ujson
ImportError: libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Environmet details:

- ujson version 1.35
- drf-ujson version 1.2
- pip version 18.1
- python version 3.6.7
- Fedora 27, linux kernel 4.19

Have you seen this error before? Can you give me some advises to debug this, please?

Comment: You might need [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) which you could install. The usual C standard library is [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)

Comment: Thank Basile, I have solved the problem by install musl-libc, then reinstall ujson. But what I don't understand is the ujson installation process via pip had done without any error and Fedora don't have musl-libc in any built in repositories. That why I hesitate to install musl-libc earlier.

Answer (score 10):

Had the same issue with amazonlinux image

Firstly you need to install musl lib. It's absent in yum so you have to compile it from source

```
curl https://musl.libc.org/releases/musl-1.2.2.tar.gz -o musl-1.2.2.tar.gz
tar -xvf musl-1.2.2.tar.gz
cd musl-1.2.2
./configure
make 
make install
```

and then

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 /usr/lib64/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1
```

if there is no file libc.so.6 in /usr/lib64 try to find it using
`find / -name 'libc.so*'` . Dest file should be at the same directory with libc.so. For instance if file has path /usr/lib/libc.so.6 your command will be `ln -s /usr/lib/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1`